# Django: show external data in model based form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have some external data (SOAP) that I want to show in a model-based-form.

The Model:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    profile_email = models.EmailField()
    company_name = models.CharField()
    coc_number = models.CharField()
    gender = models.CharField()
#etc
```

The Form:

```
 class UserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = UserProfile
```

The data is a dictionary:

```
u = {}
u['profile_email'] = 'monkey'
u['company_name'] = 'tiger'
u['coc_number'] = 'some number'
u['gender'] = 'M'
```

My question is: What is the best way to put the data into the form? What I have so far:

```
form = UserDetailsForm(initial=u)
```

This results in a form with all the data. 
1) But is this the right way to fill a model-bases-form with external data?
2) How can I set the right value in a select option (Choose country for instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is appropriate way.
2. You need to set *value* for select/choices field in the dict similar to approach 1.

For example:

```
COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
    ('IN', 'India'),
    ('US', 'USA'),
    )
    ....
    #model field 
    country = models.CharField(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)

# then set it in dict as
u = {}
u['country'] = 'IN'
u['profile_email'] = 'monkey'
u['company_name'] = 'tiger'
u['coc_number'] = 'some number'
u['gender'] = 'M'
...
```